# Does a Parkinson's Disease always reach the final stage 5

Tags: parkinson

There are five stages of Parkinson's Disease (according to https://parkinsonsnewstoday.com/parkinsons-stages/ for instance)

Are there exceptions or do patients always reach the last stage (5) - assuming they live long enough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parkinson's is a progressive disease <sup>[1](https://parkinsonsdisease.net/basics/stages/)</sup>, so in general it's going to progress through all the stages eventually for most patients, but there are very few things in medicine you can say "always" happen (except maybe that exceptions always happen).

> Although Parkinson’s disease (PD) is progressive and worsens over
>   time, it is highly individual and affects people differently. Not all
>   people who have PD will experience all the symptoms, and symptoms may
>   vary in their severity between patients. Different people experience
>   progression at different speeds, as well.

So the answer to your basic question is no, stage 5 is not a guaranteed outcome for every patient who lives long enough. It is, however, a likely outcome.

Comment: I mean, if someone dies at stage 4, how does one know they wouldn’t have reached stage 5 at some point in their hypothetical longer life? As PD is a neurodegenerative disease without a cure, I would expect everyone to go through all stages given enough time. // Lewys Bodies would continue to develop and travel to upper basal ganglia. There is no good explanation for why this process would stop at some point, given unlimited time and no prior death.

Comment: @Narusan Right, but it's that "unlimited time" thing that removes the certainty.